# Still having horizontal lines while using \multirow?

Tags: multirow

I'm pretty new to TeX in general, having only produced two `beamer`-documents so far.
Right now I'm working on my first term paper using TeX.

What I want to accomplish is a simple use of `\multirow`. However, some remaining horizontal lines bug me even though I followed my instruction step by step.

I believe the code sample speaks for itself:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Biotoptyp: Abk"urzung} & \textbf{Fl"ache 2011, in m$^2$, ca.} \\ \hline
HN                & \multirow{4}{*}{15.800} \\ \hline
BRS               &                         \\ \hline
BMS               &                         \\ \hline
HB                &                         \\ \hline
UHT               & \multirow{2}{*}{8.200}  \\ \hline
GMK               &                         \\ \hline
UHM               & 4.000                   \\ \hline
SXA               & 2.500                   \\ \hline
HFS               & 1.100                   \\ \hline
\textbf{$\Sigma$} & \textbf{31.600}         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Biotoptyp: Abk"urzung} & \textbf{Fl"ache 2011, in m$^2$, ca.} \\ \hline
HN                & \multirow{4}{*}{15.800} \\ \hline
BRS               &                         \\ \cline{1-1}
BMS               &                         \\ \hline
HB                &                         \\ \hline
UHT               & \multirow{2}{*}{8.200}  \\ \cline{1-1}
GMK               &                         \\ \hline
UHM               & 4.000                   \\ \hline
SXA               & 2.500                   \\ \hline
HFS               & 1.100                   \\ \hline
\textbf{$\Sigma$} & \textbf{31.600}         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This code produces:

[image]

PD: `\cline{i-j}` indicates that the line goes from column `i` to column `j`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the quick reply. I find it hard to believe that the authors of my guide made such a simple mistake and still they did.